# Why are my Fluent NHibernate SubClass Mappings generating redundant columns?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following entities

```
public abstract class Card
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Sprint Sprint { get; set; }
}
public class Story:Card
{
    public virtual double Points { get; set; }
    public virtual int Priority { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Story> Stories { get; private set; }

    public Product()
    {
         Stories = new List<Story>();
    }
}
```

And the following mappings

```
public class CardMap:ClassMap<Card>
{
    public CardMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id)
            .Index("Card_Id");

        Map(c => c.Name)
            .Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Description)
            .Length(1024)
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(c=>c.Product)
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(c=>c.Sprint)
            .Nullable();

    }
}
public class StoryMap : SubclassMap<Story>
{
    public StoryMap()
    {
        Map(s => s.Points);
        Map(s => s.Priority);

    }
}
public class ProductMap:ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id)
            .Index("Product_Id");

        Map(p => p.Name)
            .Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(p => p.Stories)
            .Inverse();
    }
```

When I generate my Schema, the tables are created as follows

```
Card
---------
Id
Name
Description
Product_id
Sprint_id

Story
------------
Card_id
Points
Priority
Product_id
Sprint_id
```

What I would have expected would have been to see the columns Product_id and Sprint_id ONLY in the Card table, not the Story table.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Comment: This is indeed odd. I tried duplicating this in fluent 1.1.0.0 and nhibernate 2.1.2.400 on an sqlite database and I do NOT get a `Product_id` or `Sprint_id` column in the story table. If you are not already, have you tried rebuilding the schema from scratch? And what db provider are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite also.  I downgraded to fluent 1.1.0.685 and NH 2.1.2.4000 and can still recreate the issue.  I did set all my projects to compile to x86 (i'm on win7 64, and sql throws a fit otherwise).  I will add my schema generation code also.

Comment: I simplified the code down to the bare minimum, and compiled it against both NH2 and NH3.  Same result.  I posted the projects here
https://bitbucket.org/brookpatten/stackoverflow/src/b267fbc24c5a/why-are-my-fluent-nhibernate-subclass-mappings-generating-redundant-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NB: Tested on the NH2 project only*

Well, you are probably going to want to chew on a door once you read this, but the TLDR reason is because the `Product_id` and `Spring_id` columns in your `Story` table are **not** redundant - they exist for the `HasMany(x => x.Stories)` relations in your SpringMap and ProductMap. They just happen to be share the same naming convention as the `CardMap` `References(x => x.Product` and `References(x => x.Sprint)`.

Validate this for yourself by commenting out `ProductMap.cs:24-25` and `SprintMap.cs:22` and rebuilding.

If the above does not make sense, let me know and I will try to explain in further detail.

So, it *should* work fine as is. If you want to *clarify* the columns, you could explicitly define the column names like so:

```
ProductMap.cs
        HasMany(p => p.Stories)
            .KeyColumn("ProductOwner_id")
            .Inverse();

SprintMap.cs
        HasMany(s => s.Stories)
            .KeyColumn("SprintOwner_id")
            ;

CardMap.cs
        References(c=>c.Product)
            .Column("Product_id")
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(c=>c.Sprint)
            .Column("Sprint_id")
            .Nullable();
```

Here I am guessing that the 1:N relationships between a Story and a Product/Sprint are an "owner". You would want to rename it to whatever is appropriate semantically.

One other thing. *I* would have thought the last changes (the changes to `CardMap.cs`) would be unnecessary - but they seem to be for some reason, or the `Sprint_id` column becomes `SprintOwner_id`. I have no idea why this would happen - I would speculate that this is some sort of bidirectional relationship inferencing on fluent/nhibernates part gone awry, but I'd put very little money on that.

Comment: Marking as accepted because I think you're right on the money with the explanation about what's going on.  Any ideas how to make it do what I want?

Comment: @Brook - well I would say that it *is* doing what you want, as we have established the columns in question are not redundant. I provided code snippets to name the columns explicitly... but I'm not sure if you can do better than that. Or if I'm on the wrong track, what is it exactly you want it to do?

Comment: agreed, but what I'm trying to do is have the product_id and sprint_id columns ONLY on the Card table.  Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: @Brook - to remove the product_id and spring_id columns from the Card table, you must remove the `HasMany(x => x.Stories)` definitions on your `SpringMap` and `ProductMap`. Or, an alternative (a somewhat odd alternative, and one I would not recommend) would be to push these definitions to a seperate mapping table using a HasManyToMany

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it, I'm going to post it below in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the `Story` entity inherits from the `Card` entity you created, but you don't know why you have Product_Id and Sprint_Id properties in the Story table Schema, since they're virtual properties in the Card class.

I'm guessing that this happens because in NHibernate, all properties need to be virtual but only at first. They don't really stay virtual. The NHibernate framework overrides them, and probably because of this, this is happening to you.

Comment: Name and Description are Not duplicated, but they are also virtual.  The only columns that are duplicated are the relationships.  Changing any property to non-virtual will cause a runtime error, unless i'm totally missing something.

Comment: no, you need all the properties to be marked as 'virtual'. As for the other properties that aren't duplicated, I think i need to read more about it...